# After entering the password using ssh, nothing happens

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, vnc, vncviewer

I'm trying to use SSH to connect to a VNC. When I enter the password, it just hangs with not an error message nor anything at all. How can I solve this

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 -C -N -l root 192.168.1.10
root@192.168.1.10's password:
```

Comment: You told it not to execute anything on the remote system (`-N`) and remain in foreground (no `-f`) and support any tunnel opens that occur (`-L`) (or at least try to). It's doing exactly what you said you want. If you actually want something different from what you said, the program can't read your mind, so you need to truthfully and correctly say what you want.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I consider this a valid answer. You could make it more obvious that `-f` puts the command in the background.